# Android: Button is null though created

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I attempted to create my ImageButton using a the **initializeBtn()** function but **__animateBtn** is null when I checked it running the function. Any thoughts?

When I don't attempt to catch the null **__animateBtn**, LogCat throw a null pointer exception.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

public static ImageButton __animateBtn;

public static myLayout __myLayout;  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (__animateBtn == null) {
        initializeBtn (__animateBtn, R.drawable.wrapped_leavemenu_0, false);

    }

    if(__myLayout == null) {

        __myLayout = (myLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);

        if (__animateBtn == null) {
            Log.d("__animateBtn", "null");
            finish();
        }
        if (__animateBtn2 == null) {
            Log.d("__animateBtn2", "null");
            finish();
        }
        else {
        Log.d ("__myLayout.addView", "are" + __myLayout.getChildCount());               
        __myLayout.addView(__animateBtn, new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(100,140,midX,midY-100));
        __myLayout.addView(__animateBtn2, new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(200,100,midX-100,midY));
        }

    }   

public void initializeBtn (ImageButton btn, int resid, boolean visible) {

    btn = new ImageButton (getApplicationContext());
    btn.setBackgroundResource(resid);

    if (visible) btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
}
```

Comment: yes. it is never initialized. btn = new ... does not affect __animateBtn, it reaffects the local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use :

```
public ImageButton initializeBtn (int resid, boolean visible) {

    ImageButton btn = new ImageButton (this);// use this instead of getApplicationContext()
    btn.setBackgroundResource(resid);

    if (visible) btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    return btn;
}
```

and then in your `onCreate()` method :

```
__animateBtn = initializeBtn(R.drawable.wrapped_leavemenu_0, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update a variable by providing it is a value to a method. (Java does not support *arguments by reference*, like C++ does for example).

Instead you can use a *class member field*:

```
public void initializeBtn (int resid, boolean visible) {

     __animateBtn = new ImageButton (getApplicationContext());
     __animateBtn.setBackgroundResource(resid);

    if (visible)
       __animateBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
       __animateBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Or *return* the newly created button:

```
public ImageButton initializeBtn (int resid, boolean visible) {

    ImageButton btn = new ImageButton (getApplicationContext());
    btn.setBackgroundResource(resid);

    if (visible)
       btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
       btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    return btn;
}
```

Whichever fits best in your design/ideas.

Comment: change the return type in your second approach , it will give an error because you are trying to return an ImageButton , and your method is returning void

Comment: thanks for prompt response too. I would prefer the second one, and it's more elegant. haha, I crashed into java with prior C++ experience only, and I recall this works in c++ back then.